# pandas: group by column and store count

Tags: python, pandas

How can I create a new column named "Count" such that for each row it contains the count of registered 'Gender' of corresponding row. For example in the example below there are 2 registered females and 1 registered male so for the input:

```
Gender  Registered
female  1   
female  1
female  0
male    1
male    0
male    0
```

output should be:

```
Gender  Registered Count
female  1          2
female  1          2
female  0          2
male    1          1
male    0          1
male    0          1
```

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
df[df['Registered'] == 1].groupby('Gender')['Gender'].count()
```

Comment: df[df['Registered'] == 1].groupby('Gender')['Gender'].count() does get the count. The problem would be creating the new column?

Comment: @PedroTorres yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `transform`

```
df.groupby('Gender').Registered.transform(lambda x : sum(x==1))
0    2
1    2
2    2
3    1
4    1
5    1
Name: Registered, dtype: int64
#df['count']=df.groupby('Gender').Registered.transform(lambda x : sum(x==1))
```

Comment: Also `df.groupby("Gender").Registered.transform("sum")`

Comment: @W.Dodge this only work for the edge sample, when the number need to count is equal to 1 .